# Creating web map using MapGuide Maestro?

Tags: references, mapguide

I have been given a task by my lecturer to create a web map using mapguide maestro or Autodesk Infrastructural Studio. The application that I used to finish my mapping are mapguide maestro, and the data is in shapefile. My mapguide open source are still installed and running.

Is there any site that has a tutorial to do it? I am trying to make a website that looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: I found this with a 10 second google: https://live.osgeo.org/en/quickstart/mapguide_quickstart.html

Comment: I am trying to develop a system that can view a map. I have finished my mapping, I just want my map to appear in my html page.

Comment: @PolyGeo like this.. [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LPP9s.png

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any additional details.  I am not a potential answerer of your question but anyone who is may or may not read the comments.  The question body is where all important details should go.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more Details: Which application did you use to “finish your mapping” (AutoCAD Map 3D, MapGuide Maestro, Autodesk Infrastructure Studio)? Witch data do you use (DWG, FDO like Oracle or Shapefile)? Is MapGuide Open Source or Autodesk Infrastructure Mapserver still installed and running?

Comment: @Jens ok tq.. done editing.

Comment: I would start with the Maestro User Guide (included in Maestro: Help > User Guide) or with [User Guide of Autodesk Infrastructure Studio Help](http://help.autodesk.com/view/AIMS/2016/ENU/?guid=GUID-2C5E184F-499C-4896-A4DC-ACD1E0153477) or Autodesk Infrastructure Studio Help > User Guide in the application. To publish a map as a website this topic [Displaying the Map in a Web Browser](http://help.autodesk.com/view/AIMS/2016/ENU/?guid=GUID-1B2A8520-88FC-4D3B-B6C7-915ACF8BCAD3) will help. If you search the web for information about MapGuide / Maestro / Studio beware of outdated documentation.

Comment: @Jens can i edit the template of studio??? for example i want to add banner at the top of the page..

Comment: For the question how to edit a template I would start a new thread here. I can not help you with this because we use other clients with MapGuide. Another site where you may find an answer is the [Infrastructure Map Server Forum](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/infrastructure-map-server-forum/bd-p/233) from Autodesk.